# Is there a method to generate a standard 128bit GUID (UUID) on the Mac?

Tags: cocoa, macos, guid, uuid, core-foundation

Is there a built in function equivalent to .NET's

```
Guid.NewGuid();
```

in Cocoa?

My desire is to produce a string along the lines of `550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000` which represents a unique identifier.

Comment: Rather than ask "is there an equivalent function to foo()" you should explain what the function you're asking about does. Mac OS X doesn't have "Guid" objects, it has CFUUIDRef.  Long-time Mac developers might not know a "Guid" from a hole in the ground.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

UUIDs are handled in Core Foundation, by the CFUUID library. The function you are looking for is [CFUUIDCreate](http://Developer.Apple.Com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFUUIDCreate).

FYI for further searches: these are most commonly known as UUIDs, the term GUID isn't used very often outside of the Microsoft world. You might have more luck with that search term.

Answer (score 56):

At least on MacOSX 10.5.x you might use the command line tool "uuidgen" to get your string
 e.g.

$ uuidgen

054209C4-3873-4679-8104-3C18AE780512

there's also an option -hdr with this comand that conveniently generates it in header style

See man-page for further infos.

Comment: Not precisely what OP wanted, but just as useful (and Google brought me here when searching for command line UUID generation on Macs).

Also: confirmed still working on Mac OS X 10.9 "Mavericks"

Answer (score 32):

Some code:

For a string UUID, the following class method should do the trick:

```
+(NSString*)UUIDString {
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

if you really want the bytes (not the string):

```
+(CFUUIDBytes)UUIDBytes {
    CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFUUIDBytes bytes = CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return bytes;
}
```

where CFUUIDBytes is a [struct](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CFUUIDBytes) of the UUID bytes.

Comment: @Jay: Technically, that is the Core Foundation API, which is written in C. Cocoa is written in Objective C and is a lot more terse (most of the time).

Comment: See David's answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22093094/1172352) for a simpler way to do this on 10.8+, just using `NSUUID`.

Answer (score 21):

or there's the `uuidgen` command line tool.

Comment: Thanks! I just updated it from `genuuid` to `uuidgen`.

Answer (score 10):

Since 10.8 you could also use:

```
NSString *uuidString = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can create an alias in the `~/.bash_profile` and call `uuid` from the terminal:

```
alias uuid="uuidgen | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since 10.3 or so, you can use [`[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProcessInfo/globallyUniqueString). However, while this *currently* generates a UUID, it never has been and still isn't guaranteed to do that, so if you really need a *UUID* and not just any unique string, you should use CFUUID.