# Flat or nested directory structure for an image cache?

Tags: macos, file, caching, filesystems, io

My Mac app keeps a collection of objects (with Core Data), each of which has a cover image, and to which I assign a [UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291868/) upon creation. I had originally been storing the cover images as a field in my Core Data store, but recently started storing them on disk in the file system, instead.

Initially, I'm storing the covers in a flat directory, using the UUID to name the file, as below. This gives me O(1) fetching, as I know exactly where to look.

```
...
/.../Covers/3B723A52-C228-4C5F-A71C-3169EBA33677.jpg
/.../Covers/6BEC2FC4-B9DA-4E28-8A58-387BC6FF8E06.jpg
...
```

I've looked at the way other applications handle this task, though, and noticed a multi-level scheme, as below (for instance). This could still be implemented in O(1) time.

```
...
/.../Covers/A/B/3B723A52-C228-4C5F-A71C-3169EBA33677.jpg
/.../Covers/C/D/6BEC2FC4-B9DA-4E28-8A58-387BC6FF8E06.jpg
...
```

What might be the reason to do it this way? Does OS X limit the number of files in a directory? Is it in some way faster to retrieve them from disk? It would make the code used to calculate the file's name more complicated, so I want to find out if there is a good reason to do it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On certain file systems (and I beleive HFS+ too), having too many files in the same directory will cause performance issues.

I used to work in an ISP where they would break up the home directories (they had 90k+ of them) Using a multi-directory scheme. You can partition your directories by using, say, the first two characters of the UUID, then the second two, eg:

```
/.../Covers/3B/72/3B723A52-C228-4C5F-A71C-3169EBA33677.jpg
/.../Covers/6B/EC/6BEC2FC4-B9DA-4E28-8A58-387BC6FF8E06.jpg
```

That way you don't need to calculate any extra characters or codes, just use the ones you have already to break it up. Since your UUIDs will be different every time, this should suffice.

Comment: Thanks, I'd been thinking along those lines already. I'm making the UUID an `NSMutableString` and then inserting a `/` after the first two, and the second two, characters, so now my file name is also 4 characters shorter.

Comment: Is there any penalty to breaking it down too much, though? Using your scheme of 2 directories of 2 hex digits each would mean creating at most 256^2 directories, meaning (assuming even distribution) each file will practically have its own directory.

Comment: It depends how many files you are planing on storing, but yeah, you could start with 1 digit, then if that gets too much, create sub-directories with the second digit, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is that in the latter way, as you've mentioned, disk retrieval is faster because your directory is smaller (so the FS will lookup in a smaller table for a file to exists).

Comment: So, to be clear, it takes longer to read a file from a directory that has more contents?

Comment: No. It takes longer for the OS to determine wether a file exists in that directory. Once you get the file handle, read/write time should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, on some file systems it takes longer for the OS to open the file, because one directory with many files is longer to read than a couple of short directories.

However, you should perform measurements on your particular file system and for your particular usage scenario. I did this for NTFS on Windows XP and was surprised to discover that flat directory was performing better in all kinds of tests, than hierarchical structure.